# Subtract two date columns given condition in another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

Data frame (in excel format):

```
     A                      B                        C
1  this 9/20/2020  2:33:59 PM    9/20/2020  2:34:04 PM
2  this 9/17/2020  6:39:19 PM    9/17/2020  6:24:11 PM
3  not  9/22/2020  1:23:45 AM    9/22/2020  1:23:41 AM
4  this
```

I am trying to find the difference between C and B (by computing C-B) but only if in column A == 'this' to then put those computations into a new column, D.

Preferably I'd like this in hours only, where blanks are not counted here for calculation. Columns B and C are already properly formatted for date and time. I intend to then use these hour numbers to group them into date spans for reporting.

Here is what I have so far:

```
df = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx')
print(df)

# df['D'] = (df['C']-df['B'])

df.loc[df['A'].eq('this'), 'D'] = (df['C']-df['B'])
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code now?

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't see column D when I print df

Comment: show an example of what you want it to look like

Answer (score 0):

There is probably way more elegant solution to this problem but here's one using list comprehensions.

```
# Create some data
df_arr = [["this",4.0,6.0], ["this", 5.0, 9.0], ["not", 10.0, 12.0], ["this", 14.0, 20.0]]

# Initiate DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df_arr, columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
```

DataFrame:

```
┌───┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│   │  A   │  B   │  C   │
├───┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 0 │ this │  4.0 │  6.0 │
│ 1 │ this │  5.0 │  9.0 │
│ 2 │ not  │ 10.0 │ 12.0 │
│ 3 │ this │ 14.0 │ 20.0 │
└───┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Use list comprehension 1 or 2 (both output the same values).

- Solution 1. Directly pick which columns to iterate and use "zip()"
- Solution 2. Iterate over rows in DataFrame with ".iterrows()"

```
import numpy as np
# List comprehension 1
df["D1"] = [(val_c - val_b) if val_a == "this" else
            np.nan for val_a, val_b, val_c in zip(df["A"], df["B"], df["C"])] 

# OR

# List comprehension 2
df["D2"] = [(row[2] - row[1]) if row[0] == "this" else
            np.nan for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
```

Result:

```
┌───┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬─────┐
│   │  A   │  B   │  C   │ D1  │ D2  │
├───┼──────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 0 │ this │  4.0 │  6.0 │ 2.0 │ 2.0 │
│ 1 │ this │  5.0 │  9.0 │ 4.0 │ 4.0 │
│ 2 │ not  │ 10.0 │ 12.0 │ NaN │ NaN │
│ 3 │ this │ 14.0 │ 20.0 │ 6.0 │ 6.0 │
└───┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Naturally, you can substitute "np.nan" value for other ones when column "A" is equal to "not"

Answer (score 0):

Try [`numpy.where(condition, [x, y])`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
Where `condition` True, yield `x`, otherwise yield `y`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# load your DataFrame

df['D'] = np.where(df.A == 'this', df.C - df.B, np.nan)

print(df)
      A                   B                   C                 D
0  this 2020-09-20 14:33:59 2020-09-20 14:34:04   0 days 00:00:05
1  this 2020-09-17 18:39:19 2020-09-17 18:24:11 -1 days +23:44:52
2   not 2020-09-22 01:23:45 2020-09-22 01:23:41               NaT
```

Values within column `D` become [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)(difference between two datetime objects)